# Error from python worker: /bin/python: No module named pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I am trying to establish a nice spark development environment by using ipython. First fire up ipython, then:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster('yarn-client')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

This is from application UI, I can see that executors are up on worker nodes.

[image: application ui]

However when I try this:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("/LOGS/201511/*/*")
rdd.first()
```

I get this:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, d142.dtvhadooptest.com): org.apache.spark.SparkException:
Error from python worker:
  /bin/python: No module named pyspark
PYTHONPATH was:
  /data/sdb/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdfs/filecache/64/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.startDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createThroughDaemon(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Spark is installed on the executors?

Comment: Spark is installed on all worker nodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So setting those two extra configurations did the trick.

```
conf.set('spark.yarn.dist.files','file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip,file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip')
conf.setExecutorEnv('PYTHONPATH','pyspark.zip:py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip')
```

Comment: After trying every possible trick to get the Spark 2.0.2 work with PyCharm, this did the job!

Comment: Any idea why this works? Shouldn't these files already exist on the worker nodes? Are there conflicting installations on the worker nodes?

Comment: Where do you set these config values?

Answer (score 1):

In cloudera CDH

```
conf.set('spark.yarn.dist.files','file:/path/to/pyspark.zip,file:/path/to/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip')
conf.setExecutorEnv('PYTHONPATH','pyspark.zip:py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip')
```

The above snippet solved my issue but i didn't have the rights to change the spark application code. To solve, Check your PYTHONPATH has these two zips added. In my case the default PYTHONPATH was using hardcoded nodenames in the path to these files. With below i don't need to change the application code

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip
```